# Header above Map Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to display a header with a TextView and a Spinner above a Map Fragment. The android studio preview shows my layout as I want it but when launched the map takes up the whole screen.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/rl_header"
        android:background="#FFF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miles_select_text"
            android:text="@string/miles_select_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/miles_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/miles_select_text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Image of android studio preview (how I want it too look):
[image: Android Studio Preview]

How it actually looks:
[image: how it actually looks]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: u can try exchange place of the `fragment` and child `relativeLayout` it should work

Comment: The problem is, that during Android studio preview, the logic works with condition, that you have correctly inflated Toolbar and clipped with your RelativeLayout as root. You should post also source code for the Activity/Fragment, where you have the initialization of the map and try to handle the toolbar by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering a similar issue:
As @jantursky pointed out "the logic works with condition, that you have correctly inflated Toolbar and clipped with your RelativeLayout as root". I looked at the setContentView() code and noted that android studio had set up another layout which in turned loaded my layout. I solved my problem by changing the root node of this android studio generated xml file to .